# XSL identify inner tags

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<description>Some description<tt>some more description</tt> even more description</description>
```

In my XSL file I get the data from the description tag by this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
```

The result is the FO document is

```
Some description<tt>some more description</tt> even more description
```

How can I make my XSL-Stylesheet interpret the text between the

```
<tt>
```

tags as "italic" or some other text styles like "bold" or so?

Comment: Please post a **complete** stylesheet. It can be minimal, but make it complete. The code snippet you have posted does **NOT** produce the result you claim.

Answer (score 2):

given your XML as:

`<description>Some description<tt>some more description</tt> even more description</description>`

this:

`<xsl:template match="description/tt">
  <span style="font-style: italic">
  <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/></span>
 </xsl:template>`

will produce output as:

`Some description`*`some more description`*`even more description`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make my XSL-Stylesheet interpret the text between the
>
> `<tt>`
>
> tags as "italic" or some other text styles like "bold" or so?

You could do this by writing a template that matches `tt`, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="tt">
    <italic>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </italic>
</xsl:template>
```

--

### Note:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
```

does **NOT** return:

```
Some description<tt>some more description</tt> even more description
```